# How to change color of backgrounds, Labels and Text for all View Controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, uiviewcontroller, background

I have two view controllers, on the first I have button for day/night mode, How can I set same background color, text color, labels background color for both views. I have tried to use 
constants:

```
let colors = [UIColor.black, UIColor.white]
var index = 0


UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = colors[index]
UILable.appearance().backgroundColor = colors[index]
UITextField.appearance().backgroundColor = colors[index]
...
```

But it's not working well. It is changing colors and some times stuck and not updating text color or background colors for labels after returning back on the first view.

My button dayNight:

```
@IBAction func dayNight(_ sender: Any) {
    contentView.backgroundColor = colors[index]
    firstView.backgroundColor = colors[index]
    scrollView.backgroundColor = colors[index]
    calculateOutlet.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    calculateOutlet.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    //UIView.appearance().backgroundColor = colors[index]
    //UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = colors[index]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = colors[index]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleColors[index]
    self.dayNightOulet.image = imagesBar[index]
    self.dayNightOulet.tintColor = colorsOposite[index]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = navStatusColor[index]
    //dayNight.set
    if index == colors.count - 1 && index == colorsOposite.count - 1 {
        index = 0
    } 
    else {
        index += 1
    }
}
```

For UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = navStatusColor[index] this is working good. How can I set the colors for next view?

Comment: All views like button and label are from UIView class, so if you want to change their color, you can create an extension class or custom class from `UIView`, then create function to set whatever you want. Every time `dayNight` button tapped, you call the function

Comment: @TungVuDuc I tried different ways but still can't write good working extension. Cab you give me an example.